# How to update an ipset name-based entry

Tags: iptables, firewall, ipset

I need to handle on my firewall ([Firehol](https://firehol.org/), which is then transformed into iptables) a few dynamic entries. In an ideal world I would use a name (instead of an IP address) which always points to the right IP but this does not work (for good reasons).

In order to keep a stable configuration, I am considering to use `ipset`. (EDIT: for the sake of the example below, let's assume that `www.google.com` has **only one** IP at a given time, but which may change)

```
root@srv ~# ipset create google hash:ip
root@srv ~# ipset add google www.google.com
root@srv ~# ipset list google
Name: google
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 4
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 136
References: 0
Number of entries: 1
Members:
216.58.206.228
```

I can add/delete IPs for the set. **This does not solve the problem of updating an IP**.

To take the example above, I would like to be able to re-add `www.google.com` and (if its IP changed), have `216.58.206.228` removed and replaced by its new IP.

This is not the case:

```
root@srv ~# ipset add google www.google.com
root@srv ~# ipset list google
Name: google
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 4
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 184
References: 0
Number of entries: 2
Members:
216.58.206.228
216.58.204.132
```

**Is there a mechanism which allows to update an IP in a set, to match the current resolution of a name?**

EDIT: to clarify following some answers: I do not want to solve the problem of a name which has several addresses and cover them all (say, making sure that I have all resolutions for `www.google.com`). I have a site which has one single IP, but that IP may change.

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't seem like the best way to block a web site that has many IP addresses.

Nevertheless, this will work even if you have multiple IP addresses in an ipset list:

Instead of rewriting the same ipset list, create a new list and then `ipset swap` them.

```
ipset create temp hash:ip

for address in $(dig a www.google.com +short); do
    ipset add temp $address
done

ipset swap temp google
ipset destroy temp
```

Comment: Thanks - I clarified my question (which is not about blocking sites with multiple IP addresses but ensuring that I always have the current IP for a site which i) has only one IP and ii) this IP may change). The second part of your answer is what I was looking for - hoping that there would be a built-in mechanism for updating (possibly a tuple (ip, name)).

Comment: @WoJ This _is_ the only method of updating that is completely atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two fold:

- your firewall works by blocking/allowing connections to specific IP-addresses, ranges of IP-addresses and ports. If you configure your firewall with hostnames rather than ip-addresses, it will still use ip-addresses in it's running configuration, with the ip-addresses  the hostnames resolved to, when the configuration got loaded.
- Many destinations don't use a single fixed ip-address (range) anymore but use things like CDN's, round robin and GEO DNS, anycast etc. and subsequent connections to the same destination DNS name will go to  different IP-addresses in a (nearly) unpredictable pattern.

Most organisation solve that problem by  simply blocking direct internet access entirely and mandating the use of a proxy server. On the proxy server you can easily enforce URL based access controls and  allow access to www.google.co.uk and block access to www.google.de despite the fact that those might (at times) be resolving to the same ip-address and despite the fact that the ip-address for those may change at random times.

Alternatively, organisations block DNS, only allow the usage of the DNS server they provide and run the hostname white/blacklist at the DNS level. Which will for most users be an effective access control, although easily circumvented by a skilled operator.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear - I clarified my question with an edit. All what you are saying is correct, it is just that my problem is different. I have a site which name is fixed, but it may be resolved to a different (single) IP with time. This is also not related to security (and users trying to bypass).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situations and stumbled upon this old post. I was unable to to find a solution that works right out of the box.

I agree that proxy servers are generally sufficient for *most* needs, and using a  proxy is always the better option ... when this is actually possible...

However there are still many software applications and hardware devices (particularly IoT devices) that either ignore or only partially implement proxy settings. This issue remains prevalent even in 2023, affecting some widely used online services. Unfortunately, changing or abandoning these applications isn't always a viable option. In addition there are often a lot of cloud-hosted IPs, and no warranty the IP always will be own by a given host.

To address this issue, I have designed a plugin for bind that dynamically updates ipsets. The configuration file is something like:

```
    plugin query "update-ipset.so" {
            ipset safe {
                sites  {
                    *.google.com.;
                    *.microsoft.com.;
                    *.serverfault.com.;
                };
                ttl 86400;
            };
            ipset safev6 { 
                sites {
                    *.google.com.;
                    *.microsoft.com.;
                };
                ipv6 yes;
            };
            ipset entertainment {
                sites {
                    *.playstation.com.;                   
                };
                ttl 3600;
                ipv6 no;
            };
    };
```

Now, I will install it on a server and see if this allows to let the services pass using firewall ipset rules.

I'm genuinely interested in gauging the interest in this plugin, which may be released under the GPL2 license and available on GitHub.com as a standalone module or a bind9 fork.

I encourage anyone interested to share their thoughts and feedback.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/568346)

Comment: I am sorry, this is indeed more a comment, and a way to solve the situation than a straightforward answer.  Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

That said, there is no solution without implementing "something" and this is what I proposed in my answer.